# Squaring the standard matrix of a reflection

Tags: linear-transformations

Why is it that when you square the standard matrix of a reflection mapping you obtain the identity matrix in $\mathbb R^n$? So for example if you have $refl_p:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ with normal vector $n$=$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-3\end{bmatrix}$$The standard matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}6/7&-2/7&3/7\\-2/7&3/7&6/7\\3/7&6/7&-2/7\end{bmatrix}$$and squaring this gives $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$I'm wondering why the resulting matrix is the identity matrix, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you reflect a reflection back on itself?

Comment: You obtain the original vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is the associate matrix with the linear tranformation $V$, then $A^2$ is the associate matrix with the linear transformation $V \circ V$. Reflect a vector twice on the same axis give us the same vector, this means that $\text{refl}_p^2=id$. This is why the square of the matrix is the identity.

Answer (score 0):

Diagonalize your reflection matrix.

$A = P D P^{-1}$

If $A$ is a reflection the eigenvalues are $(1,1,-1)$

$D^2 = I\\
A^2 = PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1} = PIP^{-1} = I$

Without diagonalization.

You have some plane of reflection.  If a vector is normal to the plane of reflection it gets sent to its negative.  If it is in the plane of reflection, it goes nowhere.  Any vector in the space can be broken into a component in the plane ($\mathbf p$) and a component normal to the plane ($\mathbf n$).

$\mathbf v = \mathbf p+\mathbf n\\
A\mathbf v = \mathbf p-\mathbf n\\
A^2\mathbf v = A(A\mathbf v) = \mathbf p+\mathbf n = \mathbf v$

$\forall v, A^2\mathbf v = \mathbf v \implies  A^2 = I$

Comment: Is there a way to explain without diagonalizing the matrix? We haven't done this yet in my course.

Comment: Updated with a different explanation.